# Automatically download dependency's dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, transitive-dependency

I'm creating a library "A" that imports dependency "B". When I include library "A" in a project, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` if I also don't explicitly include dependency "B" in the project's pom.

When importing dependency "A", is there a way to tell Maven to automatically include all the its dependencies including "B" (without manually declaring to import "B", since it's already in the `pom.xml` of library "A")?

Comment: B should be installed into the local repo if you build a project that depends on A. Maybe something is wrong with one of the Poms

Answer (score 1):

Transitive dependency are added by Maven automatically. If you go to a dependency loaded in local repo you will see that near the artifact (typically jar) there is its pom.xml which describes the jar dependencies. If you are using Eclipse open your project pom.xml and go to Dependecy Hierarchy tab there you will see all dependencis including transitive ones.